# Does a thread safe timer exist?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

Is there another equivalent of Timer for android which is thread safe?
Using the timer causes problems in my application while updating the gui, most of the time it complains that gui is being updated from another thread, i tried using handlers but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: "i tried using handlers but that didn't fix the problem." what happens when you use handlers with timers. I'm using `Timer` with `Handlers` and it works just fine.

Comment: I get a new error saying that the handler cannot be created on this thread and suggest to use looper.
Then i used looper and my handler worked fine, but i got the first error that the gui cannot be updated from another thread.

Comment: You should create  the `Handler` in your activity and then pass it to the `Task` object that you are using to _schedule_ your timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `postDelayed()` on any of your `Views`. Have it do its work then call `postDelayed()` again.

Or, use `runOnUiThread()` instead of messing with your own `Looper`/`Handler`.

Or, create your `Handler` as a private data member of the class with an ordinary initializer -- it would appear you are trying to create it in the background thread, which will not work.